# "ReferenceError: require is not defined", while creating React component using ES6/Babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create an React component using ES6 in JSBin, but I keep on getting the below error. Can someone explain these?

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/mudaza/1/edit?html,js,console,output)
Error: "ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at mudaza.js:17:14"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use imports or requires in JSBin. You need the bundled .js files of the libraries you want to use in your app in the `head` of your html file and then use a slightly different syntax to access the components or functions from the added libraries.

For example, to use `react-router` in a pen, you should add it in the `head` of the HTML page hosting your app:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/2.0.0/ReactRouter.min.js"></script>
```

Afterwards, in your app's source:

```
var { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory, Link } = ReactRouter;
```

instead of

```
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory, Link } from "react-router";
```

I've cloned and updated your [JSBin with these changes](https://jsbin.com/mudocozuwi/2/edit?html,js,console,output).

A very good source for most modules .js files is https://cdnjs.com/.